# SonarLint: Unable to update data from server

Tags: eclipse-mars, sonarlint, sonarlint-eclipse

When I add a new sonar lint server, I am getting the below error in eclipse mars2.

```
Unable to update data from server 'sonar'
Unable to write protocol buffer data to file C:\Users\gopinathan.m\workspace\ws_mars2_cba\.sonarlint\work\sonar\.sonartmp_7090866391184130944\8635181712377045126\active_rules\DEFAULT - Sonar 4.5 way w\ upgraded rules.pb
```

Environment Details:
Java: jdk1.7_0_79

OS: windows 64 bit

Eclipse Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)

Plugin: SonarLint for Eclipse 2.0.1.20160415-1351-RELEASE

Comment: Sonar Server Version: 5.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug on Windows, in which some names of Quality Profiles will lead to problems writing the configuration in disk:

https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SLE-56

While it is not fixed, try to rename the quality profile "DEFAULT - Sonar 4.5 way w\ upgraded rules". The problematic char here is probably '\'.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In some windows machines this plugin is working.